# Single Hotkey to conditionally trigger either 'editor.action.triggerParameterHints' or 'editor.action.showHover'?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two hotkeys:

```
{"key": "ctrl+f4", "command": "editor.action.showHover"}
{"key": "ctrl+f11", "command": "editor.action.triggerParameterHints"}
```

I will be using these two commands a lot and wan to make it easy to trigger them by combining them into a single trigger and conditionally triggering them with a `when` clause. I tried:

```
{"key": "f1", "command": "editor.action.triggerParameterHints", "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSignatureHelpProvider"},   
{"key": "f1", "command": "editor.action.showHover", "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSignatureHelpProvider"},
```

But it does not work. when the cursor is inside parenthesis pressing `f1` does trigger parameter hints but pressing `f1` when the cursor is at the function name, `editor.action.showHover` never triggers.

Is `editorHasSignatureHelpProvider` not the right condition?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editorHasSignatureHelpProvider`  won't work because it just tests for the presence of that functionality in the language server.  Not whether the item under the cursor would produce an actual signature pop-up.

So `editorHasSignatureHelpProvider`  is either always true or false by language, it does NOT vary by cursor position in the document.  What you really need is a context key that could distinguish between a parameter location and a function location and I don't think there is such a key.

I looked through the context keys and couldn't find anything that looked helpful.  I think you will have to have two different keybindings.  You could make this feature request on GitHub.

Issue on GitHub: ['when' clause context for detecting when the cursor is inside function arguments list](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204863)

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can follow it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me, I really appreciate it. As per your suggestion I went and created a feature request issue. @starball :) ['when' clause context for detecting when the cursor is inside a functions parenthesis block #204863](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204863)